# (Django) Overriding clean_field or adding model validator breaks save?

Tags: django, forms, validation, django-forms

I am trying to add some validation to a Django ModelForm, but I'm breaking the save somehow in doing so. I have a model with a FileField, and I would like for that FileField to accept only PDFs.

I wrote a validator function:

```
def validate_pdf(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('pdf'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Invalid File')
```

And I attached it to my model's FileField:

```
class MediaObject(models.Model):
    ...
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs', blank=True, validators=[validate_pdf])
```

Then when I went to use my previously functional ModelForm, I was able to select a file but that file was not uploaded or saved to the model on submission. It acted as though I had selected no file at all. If I did NOT select a file, the rest of the form worked fine. If I did select a file, then in addition to the file not saving the rest of the form failed to save as well.

I removed the validator and the form went back to working normally, but obviously without the validators I want. I tried going to the form and overriding the clean method for each field, and also the form's overall clean, but the result was the same each time - using any field with a validator attached to it breaks saving.

Am I missing something about attaching a validator to a file field?

---

(Aside: I know that looking at the file extension is a dumb way to validate a filetype. I intend to expand the validator to look at the mimetype as well, but as they say, walk before you run.)

---

Editing in some view handling to help diagnose the issue:

```
@user_passes_test(p_restricted)
def pDashCTSCBook(request, *args, **kwargs):

    user = request.user
    mo = MediaObject.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('id'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = pCTSCForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=mo)
        if form.is_valid():
            tsc = form.save()
            form.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/successpage/')

    else:
        form = pCTSCForm(instance=mo)

    return render_to_response('dir/template.html', {'mo': mo, 'user': user, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

After more poking, I can confidently say that the issue is with ValidationError never being raised. First `form.is_valid()` is called, the validators are checked, and if the test is failed then something goes awry - rather than stopping and raising the error, it keeps trying to save the invalid form. If the validators are passed however, everything works just fine. I have tried getting `ValidationError` from both django.forms and django.core.exceptions with identical results.

If I go into my validator and change it to something like this:

```
def validate_pdf(value):
   if not value.name.endswith('pdf'):
       return ValidationError(u'Invalid File') #note return rather than raise
   return value
```

Then everything works fine so long as I try to upload a PDF. If I try to upload something else, however, I get `AttributeError: ValidationError object has no attribute '_committed'`

This AttributeError is raised when the form hits `form.save()`, which tells me that even though the validator is doing its job and is executing the code underneath `if not value.name.endswith('pdf')` but that the error is not being raised.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (maybe validators expect some return value before considering the field valid):

```
def validate_pdf(value):
    if not value.name.endswith('pdf'):
        raise ValidationError(u'Invalid File')
    return
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work - I've tried `return` and `return value` with no effect.

Comment: Could you maybe try to add some `print` statements on the validation function to see where could be the problem? (`print value` before and after the test, for example)

Comment: I just found an indentation error in my view that was causing part of the issue. Now if the file I'm trying to upload passes the test, everything works fine. If it doesn't pass the test, it simply fails to save and redirects me to my success page. A failed validation is also still preventing the rest of the form from being saved as well. The issue appears to be that the validation error isn't actually raised, yet the test is being applied.

Comment: Maybe with more relevant code (your view handling that for example) we could help ^^

Comment: Did you try with `raise ValidationError(...)` instead of return? What does it do in this case?

Comment: Note that raise is used in the original validation at the top of the post. The issue that I am describing occurs specifically because raise isn't raising for some reason.

Comment: I remember, but returning the ValidationError isn't going to do any better, it has to be raised. So we're back in first step, your validation is working and the test is done correctly, BUT the ValidationError isn't raised for some reason...

Comment: Obviously returning the ValidationError doesn't work. I am attempting to provide additional information relevant to the question. By returning it you can see that the code block is being executed, so it is reasonable to assume that the code block is being executed when raise is used. But instead of raising an error it is continuing as though the form is valid. So is there an additional step to raising an error that I  missing? Do I need to bind the error to the form or something?

Comment: According to the doc, no you shouldn't be required to do something else : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/validators/#writing-validators. Sorry I'm not a big help here ^^

Comment: Maybe try to move the validator out of your model and put it in the form pCTSCForm